# How to build Explanatory Graph for Convolutional Neural Network?

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, optimization

I m reading very interesting paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.07997.pdf) that aims to interpret convolutional neural network using graph. The general idea is when there are co-related parts in layers those are likely to be semantic parts

The idea is nicely shown on this picture:
[image]

Authors use top down learning to predict and create those graph nodes.
I looks like there are couple of things that I do not understand.

(1) Since to learn subgraph it is required to pass infered locations R_L+1 how is it possible to learn the top layer?

(2) What do those M patterns learnt with greedy algorithm represent, the are learnt in layer L but correspond to layer L+1?

(3) I would really like to see like step by step how are those nodes selected cause it looks like i do not understand how are parameters theta constructed, cause in difference section of the article it looks like they are predefined with some position value, however they are said to be learnt.

The algorithm outline is below (more details in paper link):

[image]